# How can I dynamically add a button to the last item in a list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular, I'm using the ng-repeat directive to print a list of items in an array. What I'd like to do is add a button to the right of the last item in the list. I'm not aware of a non jquery way of adding this dynamically.

Here is an image of what I currently have. My button gets pushed down the list when new things get added. I'd like to see that button on the right side of the last item in the list (here it is 'acculist').

[image]

Any ideas help! Thanks everyone.

**Edit**
The button must be present at all times. Initially there will be no items in the Shopping List, so the user must always have the ability to click the button to add items to a shopping list.

Comment: can you able show your code what you did?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
<span>{{item.name}}</span> <button ng-if="$last" >Add To List</button>
</li>
```

Comment: This would be wrong if they were to filter the results, `$index` will be relative the the item in the loop. `$last` is the correct answer

Comment: Thank you Himesh please update your answer, and I will check if it works

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="my_Ctrl">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="a in items">
         <span>{{a}}</span>
         <button ng-if="$last" value="Add" ng-click="additems()">Add</button>
       </li> 
       <li ng-if="items.length===0">
          <button value="Add" ng-click="additems()">Add</button>
       </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

angular

```
  var app=angular.module("my_app",[]);
  app.controller("my_Ctrl",function($scope){
     $scope.items=["one","two","three"];
     $scope.additems=function(){
      $scope.items.push("New Items"+($scope.items.length+1));
     }
 })
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Kalai, I believe this will solve half the problem. I have added an edit/clarification